# Installing a new JRE in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java

Upon installing a new JRE in Eclipse 4.3 (on Mac OS X 10.8.4), I am given the following options:

- Execution Environment Description
- MacOS X VM
- Standard 1.1.x VM
- Standard VM

What's the difference between the final three options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to choose **Standard VM** for a vanilla JRE or JDK.

**MacOS X VM** refers to the apple implementation that is bundled with OS X until now, **Standard 1.1.x VM** is a compatibility for legacy Java 1.1 and **Standard VM** is for Standard JRE from Sun/Oracle (Vanilla) .

Comment: What if we select "Standard 1.1.x VM" using a standard JRE, or select "Standard VM" using a Java 1.1 VM?

Comment: What does Eclipse do differently based on the VM type?

Answer (score 3):

From [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-add_new_jre.htm):

> Standard VM - You will select a folder where the JRE is installed. The
> details of the JRE will be determined by scanning the location. You
> can further customize the JRE install, specifying vm arguments, source
> attachments, etc.
>
> Standard VM 1.x.x - Same options as a standard VM
> install, but the install is customized to handle the 1.x.x install

Basically, the options here let you choose the `JVM` implementation. *Standard 1.1.x* refers to compatibility with Java 1.1. *MacOS X VM* here refers to Apple's implementation.